# React 16 not loading on IE11

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

kinda new to this... unsure how to proceed. Application is not loading on IE11, I see the splash screen, but then it freezes. Here is the output:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: someDomain.com
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
SCRIPT1003: Expected: ':'
File: main.e24722a3.js, Line: 1130, Column: 62
failed to refresh auth cookie
```

clicking on the error line returns minified junk.  Unsure what to do.
I feel like the babel-polyfill is not taking affect.

Comment: Any other errors? I would start by finding this line in your code: `failed to refresh auth cookie`

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless you specify how you built your app and what is in your code.

Comment: That is all the errors in the IE11 console.

Comment: what kind of build info would you need?

Comment: Was this app previously working then broke when you updated React? Or it's always been React 16? Presumably it works in other browsers?

Comment: Always been 16. It works in other browsers. I was thinking that it was polyfill issue, but after babel-pollyfill, it still did not work.. so... no more ideas